# Default value for drop down field on custom list form

Tags: custom-list, dropdown

I have created a drop down column on custom list's form. According to the requirement first value of this field should be "Select" and this is not a mandatory field. When user creates a new item, he does not fill this field since this is not a mandatory field then he opens the item in read mode, field displays "Select" value. I want to remove it from display form like when there is a select in this field, display nothing. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to modify this, http://edinkapic.blogspot.com/2007/08/hide-field-from-newformaspx.html, to only hide on the condition.

Basically it is using JavaScript to change the display of the form, but not any values.